# The argument 'install-sshed.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist | powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh, windows-7-x64

I am adding key to windows 7 x64 using powershell

So far i have tried the below command using powershell

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file install-sshed.ps1
```

I got error like this:

> The argument 'install-sshed.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Powershell does **not** use the current directory by default if no path is supplied, to explicitly reference the current folder prepend the file name with `.\ ` => `.\install-sshed.ps1` or use an absolute path as suggested by @engineerer's answer

Comment: @LotPings: The need for an explicit path only applies to `-Command`, not `-File`;  the latter happily accepts a filename-only argument, if it refers to a file in the current directory.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like your PowerShell session is started in a different folder than your PowerShell script. Try to add the full path to your PowerShell script:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file "c:\scripts\install-sshed.ps1"
```

Alternatively, change to the directory where the `*.ps1` file is located first:

```
cd c:\scripts
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file install-sshed.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, I'd like to add that you can also use relative paths.

For instance, to run from current directory

```
powershell -execution policy unrestricted -file ".\test.ps1"
```

Or to run from nested folder:

```
powershell -execution policy unrestricted -file ".\config\test.ps1"
```

I will also recommend to add the following parameter: `-noprofile`
This will make sure no user profiles will be loaded, it is a best practice to do that when running scripts.
You can find an interesting read [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)

Comment: Yes, `Set-Location` was a mistake; I've replaced it with `cd` which works in both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell (where it is an alias for `Set-Location`). Also note that `install-sshed.ps1` _is_ a relative path - it is implicitly relative to the current directory (same as `.\install-sshed.ps1`). Good point re `-NoProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly to other answers.

It might be you've downloaded `OpenSSH-Win32_Symbols.zip` or `OpenSSH-Win64_Symbols.zip`
 - these are NOT required binaries.
You might try to download `OpenSSH-Win32.zip` or `OpenSSH-Win64.zip` version respectively.

Also it suggested that you should `cd` into `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH` but archive is in a subfolder and I had to extract it to the parent OpenSSH folder.

Extra: common issue with permissions described [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1027) by asterikx, you might find useful to reinstall openssh following these steps if something is not working properly (assuming the downloaded archive is located at `D:\Downlaods`):

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\uninstall-sshd.ps1'
del 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\'
Expand-Archive D:\Downloads\OpenSSH-Win64.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH'
copy 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\OpenSSH-Win64\*' 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\'
del 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\OpenSSH-Win64\'
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\install-sshd.ps1'
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\install-sshd.ps1'
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\FixHostFilePermissions.ps1'
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\FixUserFilePermissions.ps1'
Set-Service sshd -StartupType Automatic
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
```